# Typescript Discriminant property type not working with generic types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a schema and infer type based on the schema

However, the type of `data` is not the same I have expected, it should be `{ love: string }` instead of `{ love: string } | { eat: string }` inside the if loop

```js
const users = {
    //...
}

//Similar to zod's 'z.infer'
//This is an example type generated from 'users' schema
type Users = {
    henry: {
        data: {
            love: string;
        };
    };
    kyle: {
        data: {
            eat: string;
        };
    };
};

type UserMessage<U extends keyof Users = keyof Users> = {
    user: U
    data: Users[U]['data']
}

//example input (unknown type)
const test: unknown = { user: 'henry', data: { love: 'kyle'}}
const typed = test as UserMessage

if (typed.user === 'henry') {
    typed.data //Type: { love: string } | { eat: string }
}
```

Any recommended ways to do this thing in Typescript?

Comment: Your `UserMessage<keyof Users>` type isn't a discriminated union; each property is a union, so `user` is either key and `data` is either property; nothing prevents mismatches.  You can change `UserMessage` to be a *distributive* object type that distributes over unions properly, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mq9Ekm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have a discriminated union in `UserMessage`, just an object type with `user` and `data` properties which are unions.

To generate a discriminated union you can use the [distributive property of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type UserMessage<U extends keyof Users = keyof Users> = U extends U ?{
    user: U
    data: Users[U]['data']
}: never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwjAvDA3gKBvmAekIDoycBfHHYgZQEsBbegGwENkYoQYAvEACYByNEN4l6YAGYohNQgBUAFvTSqYbMDEQAPNowAOLRFwCeBkwHNEYFGyiIBMKchCMYQhCghCYEYEqIjGw4UOYmAKpIqBjYeASBYMimAFxxBBkwAvZsabiZBTAsIABuiGnQyJKWANzxBRR1GY31MADWpsZ5rRnZULnphRmI9hVQVWC1PQQtzXUtoeEwUSgAsogQEGzWADwR2joOYAJobYimIFLL0WiYZxdXK6gAfLH7ukcnyzAA-PkEXmQaQirT6AyeEAA2hEALqQoRgoQwyhpWxlZDUYi6fRGEySAxwWAACjgYDaYBAAHctGELABKHCgSCwBzQNKk8lUrSYLDwaJpISJZJCAA0WRyeSKpXKHg6xiEFCoTOgZgsTkwrNgbDQT3Wm22iGo9CuRNpjhIgIw6Ewgpswrpg3wZoEJDB8iGMAAej9KEA)

Or you could use a mapped type and get a union of the values from it:

```
type UserMessage<U extends keyof Users = keyof Users> = {
    [K in U]: {
        user: K
        data: Users[K]['data']
    }
}[U]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwjAvDA3gKBvmAekIDoycBfHHYgZQEsBbegGwENkYoQYAvEACYByNEN4l6YAGYohNQgBUAFvTSqYbMDEQAPNowAOLRFwCeBkwHNEYFGyiIBMKchCMYQhCghCYEYEqIjGw4UOYmAKpIqBjYeASBYMimAFxxBBkwAvZsabiZBTAsIABuiGnQyJKWANzxBRR1GY31MADWpsZ5rRnZULnphRmI9hVQVWC1PQQtzXUtoeEwUSgAsogQEGzWADwR2joOYAJobYimIFLL0WiYZxdXK6gAfLH5BADaANIwkssAut0hl5kGkvtN8H0Bk8IN9-h8hFChP9WlQKB8Iij5Lp9EYTJIDHBYAAKOBgNpgEAAdy0YQsAEocKBILAHNA0mSKdStJgsPBomkhIlkkIADRZHJ5IqlcoeDrGIQUKjM6BmCxOTBs2BsNBPdabbaIaj0K7EumOEggjDoTBCmwi+mDfDmgQkKHyIYwAB6AH5KEA)